# Что такое next release?

Tags: git, git-flow

Начал использовать [git-flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html). Мне предлагается выбрать ветку для `production release`:

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
   - DVR-1570
   - DVR-1573
   - develop
   - master

Branch name for production releases: [master]
```

Здесь всё понятно. Не ясен следующий тезис:

```
Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
   - DVR-1570
   - DVR-1573
   - develop
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop]
```

Что такое `next release`? У нас некст релиз всегда была фича-бранч. В них всё тестировалось и уезжало в мастер сразу и деплоился контейнер.

Поясните, что такое `next release`?

Comment: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html#getting_started тут красивая диаграмма, которая все объясняет.

Comment: @RomanKonoval но это не очень отвечает на вопрос. Объясните для глупых, плес.

Comment: Обычно ветку, где ведётся разработка, и ветку, откуда публикуются релизы, разделяют. Релизы штука хрупкая, очень легко сломать, поэтому изменения из ветки разработки затягиваются в явном виде.

Если у вас разработка это develop, а релиз это master, то next release это develop, поскольку именно там копятся фичи для следующего релиза.

Когда итерация (спринт) закончится, тестируете, перетягиваете все изменения в ветку релиза (master) и разворачиваете.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko а смысл разделять релизы? Ну, ставишь тег -- вот тебе и релиз. Разработку веди в фича-бранче. Зачем что-то ещё? Зачем девелоп? Закончил фичу -- кати на тест. Протестировал руками -- кати на прод. В каком месте возникает девелоп?

Comment: @hedgehogues, обычно решает простые вопросы синхронизации и безопасности. Скажем, если есть лаг между "показом" и выкладкой в продакшн, может возникнуть ситуация, что в ветке разработки появляются новые непротестированные фичи, и они по недосмотру уходят на прод. Если ветки две, то изменения затягиваются в ветку релиза, и будут разворачиваться оттуда, а ветка для разработки уже доступна для новых фич. Опять-таки, можно ограничить разработчиков в правах, чтобы они случайно не сломали что-нибудь. develop их ветка, а release уже не их.

Comment: Ну а вообще, смотрите. В git нет какого-то признанного единственного сценария. Одно дело, если вы один работаете. У меня вот все пет-проекты на гитхабе, при этом я никаких веток не создаю, работают в мастере. Если небольшая команда, алгоритм совместной работы станет сложнее. Если большая команда — намного сложнее. GitFlow подходит для больших команд, а для небольших он слишком сложный. Можно делать так, как удобнее команде.

Answer (score 1):

`next release` ветка нужна в большой команде для распараллеливания разработки  и тестирования.

Вот представьте, у вас команда из 10 разработчиков. Каждый из них начинает работу над фичей F1, F2, ... F10. Каждая из них порождена от некоторого комита  R1.

Допустим, используется простой процесс, когда ветку с фичей сразу сливаем в master и разворачиваем на проде.

Когда готова F1 - все в порядке, слили и все нормально. Но дальше возникают проблемы. В F2 у нас нет изменений из F1 (ведь эта ветка порождена от R1). Тут возникает дилемма: надеяться что изменения в F1 и F2 никак друг на друга не влияют (тогда можно F2 тестировать в ветке и сливать в develop) или сливать `master` в F2 и тестировать что и F1 и F2 работают как нужно.

Так как работа ведется параллельно, и веток типа F2 у нас много, то возникают проблемы с тем, что один и тот же функционал (в данном случае F1) потенциально нужно тестировать в F2-F10 несколько раз. А еще если учесть что после слияния, скажем, F2 в `master` нужно будет делать то же и для F2, то количество таких проблем возрастает.

Есть несколько способов как решить (или смягчить) проблему и схема с `next release` это один из них. В этом подходе каждая фича тестируется отдельно в ветке с фичей, потом сливается в `next release` ветку, и когда все F1-F10 слиты, делается один раунд тестирования (в этом месте его можно распараллелить). Если все нормально, то делается релиз.

Альтернативные способы решить эту проблему (и сливать ветки с фичами в develop напрямую):

1. делать так, чтоб изменения в F1 - F10 не могли друг на друга влиять
2. хорошее покрытие автоматическими тестами (по сути необходимость повторного многократного тестирования фич тут не проблема, так как все автоматизировано и мы можем это себе позволить).
3. держать маленькие команды. Тогда накладные расходы на перекрестное тестирование не такие большие (особенно если еще и пункты 1-2 на каком-то уровне), как расходы на поддержание более сложного и медленного процесса.